# Show $r(K_4,K_5) \leq 25$

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Show that the ramsey number $r(K_4,K_5) \leq 25$.

EDIT:  The original problem wording is as follows,  Show that if $G$ is a graph of order 25 that does not contain $K_4$ as a subgraph then $G$ contains 5 vertices no two of which are connected.

My attempt:  Firstly notice  that $$deg_{G}(u)+deg_{\overline{G}}(u)=24$$
Therefore by the pigeonhole principle we obtain that either, $deg_{G} \geq 12$ OR  we have $deg_{\overline{G}}(u) \geq 12$.  Now WLOG we consider the case when $deg_{G}(u) \geq 12$.  Denote $N(u)=\{v_1,v_2 \cdots v_{12}\}$ to be the set of vertices of that are adjacent to the vertex $u$.  Now we notice that between the 12 vertices if we get a $K_3$ then including $u$ we get a $K_4$ so we consider the ramsey number $r(3,5)=14$.  However we only have 13 vertices so we cannot conlude anything however this does rule out all cases in which $deg_{G}(u) \geq 13$ and so we conclude that $deg_{G}(u)=deg_{\overline{G}}(u)=12$ for all $u \in V(G)$.  Now from here is where i'm unsure how to contine, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Oops your right it should be $r(K_4,K_5) \leq 25$ thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Was this assigned as a homework problem?? Apparently the result was obtained by "a long computation" by [Mckay and Radziszowski](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/r45.pdf). The lower bound $r(K_4,K_5)\ge25,$ while challenging enough, might be a more reasonable task.

Comment: Yes this was assigned as homework.. however the wording of the problem is a bit different but it boils down to the same thing, I'll edit including the original wording.

Comment: Your "WLOG" is unjustified because $G$ and $\overline G$ are not treated symmetrically: you are looking for a $K_4$ in $G$ or a $K_5$ in $\overline G.$

Comment: Not that it's going to help much, but "$\deg_G(u)\ge12$ or $\deg_{\overline G}(u)\ge12$" could be improved to $"\deg_G(u)\ge12$ or $\deg_{\overline G}(u)\ge13.$"